# Android Room many-to-many select by nested item ID

Tags: android, android-room

I have a Room scheme like this:

```
@Entity
public class Student{
  @PrimaryKey
  private int sId;
  private String name;
  private String email;
} 

@Entity
public class Group{
  @PrimaryKey
  private int gId;
  private String name;
}

@Entity(foreignKeys = {
        @ForeignKey(entity = Student.class,
                parentColumns = "sId",
                childColumns = "studentId"),
        @ForeignKey(entity = Group.class,
                parentColumns = "gId",
                childColumns = "groupId")
})
public class StudentGroup{
  private int studentId;
  private int groupId;
}

public class StudentWithGroups{
   @Embedded
   Student student;
   @Relation(
         parentColumn = "sId",
         entity = Group.class,
         entityColumn = "gId",
         associateBy = @Junction(
                 value = StudentGroup.class,
                 parentColumn = "studentId",
                 entityColumn = "groupId)
   )
   List<Group> groups;
}
```

Where I can get all the students using this DAO:

```
 @Dao
 public interface StudentDao {
   @Query("SELECT * FROM Student")
   List<StudentWithGroups> getGroupsOfStudent()
}
```

Nice and easy so far - but what if I have to select a list of StudentWithGroups by group ID?  **Do I have to use the usual "JOIN ON" query scheme for nested list selection or where is a more simple way to do it in the Room?**

(note: I've seen [the View scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58297705/search-query-using-android-room-relation) but it's not that elegant with all the joins and it doesn't seem to select the nested list, just a single matching item)

Comment: I'm afraid you have to use loops for your "nested" lists

Comment: check @Relation - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/Relation